# cache jquery selector with desgin patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I'm trying to create my script with module pattern and cache the selectors that I usually use... but this don't work. what is the best way to do this ?

```
            var s, login = {
            settings: {
                window: $(window),
                menu: $("#menu"),
                container: $('#container'),
                login: $('#login'),
                senha: $('#senha')
            },
            init: function() {
                s = this.settings;
                self = this;

                s.window.bind('resize', function() {
                    self.adjusts();
                });
                this.adjusts();
            },
            adjusts: function() {
                s.menu.height($(window).height());
            }

        };
        $(function() {
            login.init();
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what exactly isn't working, the pattern works just fine, here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqp9P/1/), so you probably have a typo or messed up the scope etc. and the error will show up in your console.

Comment: @adeneo this is what I'm getting http://jsfiddle.net/qjvPc/. The blue bar of the top should be "covering" the page. The problem is that the DOM is not ready to jquery selectors, but how to do this? the login.init() is called when de DOM is ready. Should I put the settings content inside init? thanks